# Rounding of NSdate to nearest hour in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate, nscalendar, nsdatecomponents

I have data in the format

time: 13:52, 10:30, 11:48

etc

I would like to  round to the nearest hour.

like for 13:52 -> 14:00 , 10:30 -> 11:00 and 11:48 -> 12:00.

How can I do that with NSDate?

Comment: 1. Split your NSDate into components 2. Add if-else and check if minutes are greater than 30 3. Zero your minutes and increase your hours by one or do nothing. Thats it. Simple mathematics :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this method

```
- (NSDate*) nextHourDate:(NSDate*)inDate{
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [calendar components: NSEraCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit| NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit fromDate: inDate];
    [comps setHour: [comps hour]+1]; //NSDateComponents handles rolling over between days, months, years, etc
    return [calendar dateFromComponents:comps];
}
```

This will give you the date in next hour for the inDate

Comment: Hey Hi @Lithu T.v, I am setting time zone to UTC, if I use your code, If the system time(Indian Time) is 6.10 pm , I am getting 7.30 pm, Similarly I change time zone to US on device under settings and then try and if the time is 8.20 am I get 9.00 am. I am not understanding why?

Comment: This is more of a ceil function. If you have 10:15, it won't be rounded to 10. Instead it will changed to 11:15.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a Swift 3.0 implementation that gets the nearest hour, using a `Date` extension:

```
extension Date {
    func nearestHour() -> Date? {
        var components = NSCalendar.current.dateComponents([.minute], from: self)
        let minute = components.minute ?? 0
        components.minute = minute >= 30 ? 60 - minute : -minute
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: components, to: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you also need to remove the seconds?

Comment: For seconds, I modified the above to get seconds, then set components.seconds to -components.seconds

Answer (score 4):

```
 func nextHourDate() -> NSDate? {
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let date = NSDate()
    var minuteComponent = calendar.components(NSCalendarUnit.MinuteCalendarUnit, fromDate: date)
    let components = NSDateComponents()
    components.minute = 60 - minuteComponent.minute
    return calendar.dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using components is not reliable due to a couple of reasons:

1. Seconds are not taken into account
2. When adding seconds, rarely it misses one second

The most reliable way I found in **Swift 4.*** is:

```
extension Date {
    func nearestHour() -> Date {
        return Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:
                (timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate / 3600.0).rounded(.toNearestOrEven) * 3600.0)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is based on reference date starting from 00:00. But what about [leap seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Below code. It must help for you.

```
  NSString *dateString=@"17:15";
    NSArray *strings = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

int firstPart=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strings[0]] intValue];
int lastPart=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strings[1]] intValue];

NSLog(@"LAST:%d",firstPart);

if (lastPart>0) {

    int output=firstPart+1;



    NSString *finalOutput=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d:00",output];

     NSLog(@"OUTPUT:%@",finalOutput);
}
else
{
     NSLog(@"OUTPUT:%@",dateString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Swift 4/5 version -

```
func nextHourDate() -> Date? {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let date = Date()
    var minuteComponent = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    var components = DateComponents()
    components.minute = 60 - minuteComponent
    return calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: date)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func nextHour() -> Date? {
    guard let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: self) else { return nil }
    return Calendar.current.dateComponents([.era, .year, .month, .day, .hour], from: date).date
}
```